# Laravel Storage "Permission denied" during deleting a folder

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, file-permissions

Business-logic of my application is:

- I upload a `.zip` archive;
- Unpack it with the help of [this](https://github.com/Chumper/Zipper) package;
- Parse files;
- And the next step is deleting the folder.

But I have a fail on the last step with the following message:

[image: my error]

I've tried `chmod -R 777` for `storage` Laravel directory. But it worth to note, that it solves my problem for one uploading. On the next time I will have the same directory with the same permission problem.

I will give more detail about my code. I use Laravel's queues. The code is:

```
class RepoService
{
    public function saveRepo(UploadedFile $repoFolder): void
    {
        $originalClientFileName = $repoFolder->getClientOriginalName();
        $dirName = str_replace('.zip', '', $originalClientFileName);

        $repoFolder->storeAs('uploads', $originalClientFileName);

        // adding unpacking, saving and calculating assessment tasks
        UnpackRepoJob::withChain([
            new SaveRepoTextJob($dirName)
            // following tasks is here ... 
        ])->dispatch($dirName);
    }

    public function deleteRepoFolder(string $name): void
    {
        Storage::deleteDirectory("/uploads/$name");
    }
}
```

Tasks of the queue will unpack `zip`, pars files and so on. 
I have the following UI
[image: ui]

After click on the `Delete` button I need to delete the folder from file system.

The path to the upload directory is `/storage/app/uploads`.

Permissions on the files is 
[image: permissions img]

What do you think where is the problem? Maybe I need give more permissions for `www-data` user?

Comment: do you need change the owner https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php

Comment: Thank you, I have tried `chown()` and `chmod()` functions. I have similar result: 
`"message": "chmod(): Operation not permitted",`

Comment: The error suggests that the user unziping the file and the one trying to delete it are not the same. Or that the file might be still "open" by one of the process.

Have you verified under which user your app is running, and under which user the files are being extracted?